# Angularjs using ng-repeat with <th> tag for repetitive column headers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a table with multiple rows and one of the rows containing repetitive column headers like below.

I'm not sure how to use `ng-repeat` in `angularjs` to create these headers. I tried putting `ng-repeat` in `<tr>` element which obviously won't work as it creates multiples rows.

I also tried putting it in a `<th>` element but the headers won't appear alternatively.

I want to use `ng-repeat` (to display Current and Prior headers) rather than manually typing them like in the code below because number of times the the repetitive columns appear is dynamic (dependent on row 1).

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="item" scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" rowspan="2">Items</th>
        <th ng-repeat="year in years()" id={{year}} scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
            {{ year }}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <th  id="{{year}}planning" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Current</th>
            <th  id="{{year}}reporting" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Prior</th>
            <th  id="{{year}}planning" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Current</th>
            <th  id="{{year}}reporting" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Prior</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[image]

Comment: Code formatting and grammar

Answer (score 1):

There is ng-repeat start and end directive for this kind of situations:

```js
angular.module("Test", []).controller("repetition", 
    function($scope)
    {
      $scope.years = function()
      {
        return [2017, 2018];
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app="Test" ng-controller="repetition">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="item" scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" rowspan="2">Items</th>
        <th ng-repeat="year in years()" id={{year}} scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
            {{year}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat-start="year in years()" id="{{year}}planning" style="background-color:#EEEEEE" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Current</th>
        <th ng-repeat-end id="{{year}}reporting" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Prior</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Everithing in between the tags containing ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end will be included in the repetition.
By the way the same exists for ng-if (ng-if-start/ng-if-end)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the picture you provided, the solution lies in wrapping "current" and "prior" `<th>` with a `<div>` with ng-repeat directive. Like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="item" scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" rowspan="2">Items</th>
        <th ng-repeat="year in years()" id={{year}} scope="colgroup" style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
            {{year}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div ng-repeat="year in years()">
            <th id="{{year}}planning" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Current</th>
            <th id="{{year}}reporting" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Prior</th>
        </div>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I did try that. For some reason header appears only once rather than 2 times. And I wasn't sure if it was right to put div tag inside tr.

Comment: and when I try this <div ng-repeat="year in planYears()">
      <th  id="{{year}}planning" scope="col" class="tsub-head">{{year}} Current</th>
      <th  id="{{year}}reporting" scope="col" class="tsub-head">Prior</th>
     </div> .  {{ year }} is empty

Comment: correction it was ng-repeat="year in years() and not planYears() and as I s said {{year}} was interestingly had nothing in it.